# Check if a file is a valid SQLite database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, com, interop

I need to check whether a file (with unknown extension) is a valid SQLite database.

My function works fine, but when it fails, the file is still locked after exiting the function:

```vb
Public Function IsSqliteDB(ByVal uPath As String) As Boolean

    'Workaround for my problem: Make a copy and work on this because this function is going to lock the file unfortunately
    Dim sNewPath As String
    sNewPath = Settings.Locations.Folder_LocalAppData_Temp & "\temp_" & Replace(Now.ToString, ":", "_") & ".db"

    modIO.FileForceCopy(uPath, sNewPath)

    Dim bIsSQLiteDB As Boolean = False

    Dim c As New dhRichClient3.cConnection
    Dim r As dhRichClient3.cRecordset


    Try
        Dim b As Boolean = c.OpenDB(sNewPath) 'returns true although this is not an sqlite-db. Can't do anything about it
        R = c.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
        bIsSQLiteDB = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        r = Nothing
        c = Nothing
    Finally
        r = Nothing
        c = Nothing
    End Try

    modIO.DeleteFile(sNewPath)'this fails. File is locked

    Return bIsSQLiteDB

End Function
```

Does anybody see where I could ensure that the file is not locked anymore? Or do I really have to work with a copy of the file because the behaviour of the COM component is not really known (closed source unfortunately)?
I could indeed work with a backup, but the file may be really large (> 1 GB), so I would like to avoid making a copy to work on if I could avoid it.

There is no "close" function in dhRichClient. "Close" is called internally once the cConection goes out out scope, I guess. Calling GC.Collect() at the end of the function does not help.

Comment: If the `dhRichClient` implements `IDisposable` one could try to do `Using drc As New dhRichClient() : .. : End Using` inside the `Try/Catch`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not.

Comment: And how about the `cConnection`? :p

Comment: There is no .Close function and it is not IDisposable.

Comment: Okay. Well, I don't know `SQLite` that well. _But_ one should create **all** relevant objects _inside_ the `Try/Catch` and **not** swallow the (potential) exception. Here's an example: `Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing : Try : 'DB stuff... : Catch ex As Exception : [error] = ex : Finally : 'Cleanup... : End Try : If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then MessageBox.Show([error].Message)`  (Where `:` is a newline.)

Comment: In other words: In your code, `c` is never set to `Nothing` if an error is thrown.

Comment: Could you post a code with try / catch etc.? I tried to implement it, but I think I did something wrong.

Comment: I have edited my posting to show my current approach. This does not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine if a file is an SQLite database, just check the first 16 bytes of the [database header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header).

from tmighty's comment:

```vb
Public Function IsSqliteDB(ByVal uPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim bytes(16) As Byte
    Using fs As New IO.FileStream(uPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, 16)
    End Using
    Dim text As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
    Return text.Contains("SQLite format")
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Perhaps you could just post this code to help other users? ->     Public Function IsSqliteDB(ByVal uPath As String) As Boolean

        Using fs As New IO.FileStream(uPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            Dim bytes(16) As Byte
            Dim x As Integer = fs.Read(bytes, 0, 16)
            fs.Close()
            Dim text As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

            Dim b As Boolean = text.Contains("SQLite format")
            Return b
        End Using

    End Function