# Check if file is a valid SQLite database with SQLCipher encryption

Tags: sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

Is there any way to verify that a file is a valid SQLite database with SQLCipher, without knowing the encryption key? In other words, a**re there any checksums or magic words that do not get encrypted?**

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275154/check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-sqlite-database) I understand normal SQLite 3 databases just start with the string "sqlite 3", and if I know the password I could check validity of the actual high-level database structure [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888529/how-to-tell-if-sqlite-database-file-is-valid-or-not).

The error message “file is encrypted or is not a database” [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786784/sqlite-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database?rq=1) **suggests that the answer is no** - but can anybody confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
An encrypted database file is indistinguishable from a file containing random data.

Answer (score 0):

I solve by this code in constructor of DBHelper (it is not pure clean, but it works...)

```
private DBHelper() {
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);

    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);

    try {
        if (dbFile.exists()) { // is db file exists?
            // check if db file can be opened
            SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getAbsolutePath(), DB_PASSWORD, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE).close();
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException ex) { // it's impossible open db file - we must encrypt it
        encryptDatabase(context, dbFile);
    }
}
```